# Get the name of department with max salary SQL

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database with three tables that I need to return the name of the department with the highest salary costs from using SQL, what would be the most efficient query to do this. Been racking my brain with this one all day.

```
|----------------------------------------|
|             Departments                |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      id             |    name          |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        1            |   physics        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        2            |    math          |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

```
|------------------------------------------------|
|             Empoyees                           |
|------------|------------------|----------------|
|      id    |    name          |  department-id |
|------------|------------------|----------------|
|        1   |    mike          |       1        |
|------------|------------------|----------------|
|        2   |    frank         |       1        |
|------------|------------------|----------------|
|        3   |    bob           |       2        |
|------------|------------------|----------------|
```

```
|----------------------------------------|
|             Salaries                   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      employee-id    |    salary        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        1            |   1000           |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        2            |    2000          |
|---------------------|------------------|
|        3            |    3000          |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join and aggregate, then order and limit:

```
select d.name, sum(s.salary) sum_salary
from departments d
inner join employees e on e.department_id = d.id
inner join salaries s on s.employee_id = e.id
group by d.id, d.name
order by sum_salary desc
limit 1
```

`limit` is not supported in all databases, but they (almost) all have alternatives.

Comment: thats the trick! I couldn't for the life of me figure it out, I definitely over thought it!